# How to render Razor code stored in a resource file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Let us assume that we have some entry in a resource file which has Razor syntax. For instance:

> Key   Value
>
> Test  @Html.ActionLink("link", "Index")

Is there any way to render it in a view without using external libraries?

Comment: If you want to dynamically inject C# code (which I think you're actually trying to achieve here) I don't think it's possible without Roslyn.

Comment: I think it could be possible with RazorEngine, but it's not a case for such a tool. It seems to be rather simple, so I would be surprised if it'd be impossible with standard set of MVC tools. Could you give me some clue how it could be achievable with Roslyn?

Comment: I don't think that is the purpose of resource files. I am also not sure why someone would want to do such a thing.

Comment: @JamieRees Yes and no. To be honest, a colleague asked me whether this is possible, I don't know even why he wanted to do it like that, but I believe there may be some usage of it - for example if we have resource based internationalization we could place ActonLinks different for each language (yes we can differentiate in one action method, but why not in resource actually...). I'm just curious if this is possible.

Comment: Even the different action link per language. That's not even a good idea since you would have to write more code (action methods) for each language. Just tell your colleague it's a silly idea.